# Receiving corrupt data with pyserial

Tags: python, byte, pyserial

I've been trying to receive serial data using USB to RS422 device which is a 'MOXA UPort 1130'  with baudrate of 115200, 8 bits of data, no parity and 1 stop bit from lattice ecp5u FPGA,. as you see in 'vovsoft serial port monitor' with said settings like [this](https://files.catbox.moe/olggd1.png), which is okay, but whenever I try it in python using code below, I get the following result.

```
import serial

ser = serial.Serial( 
    port='COM3', 
    baudrate=115200, 
    stopbits=1, 
    parity='N', 
    bytesize=8 
    )
while True: 
    value = ser.readline(8) 
    print(value)
```

```
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'
b'\xab\xcd\xb8\x14\x05\x00\xe24'
b'\xab\xcd\xb8\x14\x05\x00\xe24'
b'\xab\xcd\xb8\x14\x05\x00\xe24'
… etc. …
[Done] exited with code=1 in 1.099 seconds
```

As you see, received data seems like it is missing a 4 bit worth of hex value: It should be `AB CD 38 14 05 00 DA E9` or `AB CD B8 14 05 00 E2 34`
but it's either `b'\xab\xcd8\x14\x05\x00\xda\xe9'` or `b'\xab\xcd\xb8\x14\x05\x00\xe24'`.

Am I missing something? Should I add anything to my code?

I tried adding `reset_input_buffer` in while loop, out of while loop, after opening. But it just changed telorance of wrong answers.

Comment: You are not missing anything. Byte `38` prints as character `'8'` and byte `34` prints as character `'4'`. Other bytes `AB` print as `'\xab'`.